# Error with marginnote.sty when using tufte-book

Tags: tufte

When I am trying to compile my tufts-book I get the following error,

this is the last bit of the log,

```
`(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tcolorbox/tcbfitting.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbfitting.code.tex' version '6.2.0'
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/lmodern.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sidenotes/sidenotes.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/marginnote/marginnote.sty

! LaTeX Error: Command \marginnote already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                              
 l.321 }
   
?
```

`

I have tried commenting out any packages that could possible interfere with marginnote but to no avail. This is the code in the .sty file

```
\newcommand*{\marginnote}{%
  \@dblarg\@mn@marginnote
}
```

Comment: well tufte-book defines its own \marginnote command. If you don't care about it you can do `\let\marginnote\undefined` before loading the marginnote package.